# How to Log Exceptions to Azure application logs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.Net MVC Web Application hosted in Azure Web Service. I need to log Exceptions to Application Log.

Later I want to check and review what kind of exceptions happened.

How can I do it?

Comment: by Exceptions-- all exceptions not just the ones inside try catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by exceptions you mean those caught inside a try-catch then you could do;

1. Follow the steps mentioned here, you need to toggle this setting on your Azure web app;

   [Your App > App Service Logs > Turn On Application Logging (FileSystem)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)
2. Then use the code below; `Trace.Information(), Trace.Warning(), Trace.Error()`

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public ActionResult sample(){
   try{
      Trace.Information("Hello World!");
   }catch(exception e){
      Trace.Error(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: How can i retrieve the Error Logs?

Comment: @UdaraEshanAriyarathne To stream logs in the Azure portal, navigate to your app and select Log stream.

Comment: @JerdineSabio so wont it just get the logs from log.info() /Error()? with ISpark logger?

Comment: This helped, With other Logger vendors are not getting collected

Answer (score 1):

Once you'll install [ApplicationInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) nuget package and add `InstrumentationKey` in your config file, you are ready to push application logs in Azure.

```
   private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [RequestSizeLimit(40000000)]

    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

You can view all your log data under ApplicationInsights `traces` and `Exceptions' collection